# is there a database with each wireless network exact location?

Tags: gps

If I turn wi-fi on, the gps reading becomes very accurate. However, if it is off, the location has a error margin of even 2-3miles. How does having wi-fi help, even if I did not connect to any network? Do this networks broadcast their position, and where is stored the position for each router?

Comment: On what device? Smart phone or laptop?

Comment: smartphone. How can it determine the location based on nearby networks? it must know the routers position to do this..

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how it works.

When you have an Internet connection, you can download [DGPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_GPS) data from the Internet. DGPS data provides corrections for satellite position errors, satellite clock errors, and variations in atmospheric propagation that reduce GPS accuracy. In the United States, these corrections come from the [NDGPS](http://www.gps.gov/systems/augmentations/) initiatives. Other countries have similar projects.

Comment: I am inside my house. I turn on wireless on my android device, and it locates me, even though I dodnot connect to my network. On the other hand it I turn wifi off, the accuracy is very bad (2-3miles off). So I assume it is because of the wireless networks the device sees

Comment: I don't follow you. What changes when you are inside your house? If you don't connect to the network, why do you think it has anything to do with the network?

Comment: I doubt that any phone would have DGPS. It's more something found on ships. Phones have AGPS for starting quicker.

Comment: well because if I turn wifi off on the phone, the accuracy is 3 miles.